# Keras VGG16 ValueError: "Output of the generator should be tuple but got 'None'." How can I solve this?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am fine-tuning a VGG16 pretrained model with my own dataset which has of 2 categories. When I try to run `model.fit_generator()` I get this error:

`output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None'.`

But `flow_from_directory` finds the images as I can see from the terminal.

How can I solve this problem? Please Help!

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.utils import *
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import Input,Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'dataset/train',
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'dataset/evaluate',
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')


from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np


input_shape=(64, 64, 3)

inputs = Input(shape=(64,64,3))

base_model = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
x = base_model.output
x = Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:])(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='predictions')(x)
model = Model(base_model.input , x)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=   ['accuracy']) 


#train_generator = np.asarray(train_generator)
#validation_generator = np.asarray(validation_generator)
validation_generator = np.expand_dims(validation_generator, axis=2)
validation_generator = np.expand_dims(validation_generator, axis=3)

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your full code so that others can see what you have done and can help you. Also try to always format your questions, especially code blocks.

Comment: Thanks for providing the full code. To make it more legible please remove any unneccesary code lines especially code that is commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top layer seems wrong for two classes. Change it to

```
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='predictions')(x)
model = Model(base_model.input , x)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=   ['accuracy'])
```

I also suggest you add a full classifier model on top of your "headless" VGG16 base like you see in the Keras example code:

```
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

https://gist.github.com/fchollet/7eb39b44eb9e16e59632d25fb3119975

You also should remove the `classes` argument from this line:

```
base_model = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape, classes=2)
```

See Keras documentation for VGG16 application here: https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16

Comment: Thanks for help! Now I am having the error: 'ValueError: validation_data should be a tuple `(val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)` or `(val_x, val_y)`. Found: [[<keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x7fe26399dbe0>]]'

Comment: Ok. Add `(x)` to this line: `x = Dense(256, activation='relu')`.

Comment: One of these lines is redundant: `x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)`
`x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='predictions')(x)`

Comment: And why do you `expand.dims` on the validation generator? What happens if you comment that out?

Comment: It expects the input to have 4 dimensions but originally it is (24,1)

Comment: Adding the layers solved the problems. I guess I mistyped a line in my code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great. Happy to hear that you could fix the problem. You can accept my answer as the answer by upvoting so that others can see that the matter is resolved.

Comment: Did it! But I am below 15 rep :)